# setSelected() on ToggleButton does not change its appearance

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I have a ToggleButton in a Fragment subclass that I can only call setSelected() on the first time - after that, setSelected() does change the property when I debug with isSelected(), however the appearance of the ToggleButton itself does not change.

In my AddEditTripFragment extends Fragment class:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
    ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_edit_trip, container, false);

    ...

    mondayButton = v.findViewById(R.id.mondayButton);
    final Trip myTrip = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).tripToEdit;
    // Check if tripToEdit is not null, so we can pull the values to populate the date/time
    if (myTrip != null) {
        ...
        mondayButton.setChecked(myTrip.isMonday());
        mondayButton.setSelected(myTrip.isMonday());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: myTrip.Monday() = " + myTrip.isMonday());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: mondayButton.isSelected() = " + mondayButton.isSelected());
        ...
    }
```

Output:

```
... onCreateView: myTrip.Monday() = true
... onCreateView: mondayButton.isSelected() = true
```

Yet the ToggleButton's appearance is still "turned off".

I haven't added any listeners to the ToggleButton yet.

What can I do to have the ToggleButton change the appearance when I do .setSelected() on it?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trying different things, I found the only solution that worked in a Github issue: https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/199#issuecomment-89126286

Replace

```
mondayButton.setChecked(myTrip.isMonday());
mondayButton.setSelected(myTrip.isMonday());
```

For this:

```java
mondayButton.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mondayButton.setChecked(myTrip.isMonday());
        mondayButton.setSelected(myTrip.isMonday());
    }
});
```